# React Native - (0, _redux.combineReducers) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, reducers

I'm currently learning some redux in React Native. But i keep stumbling on one error if i try to combine my reducers in a index.js file.

```
(0, _redux.combineReducers) is not a function
```

I watched some tutorials for how to use this and I follow with every step but it's keep coming on my screen.

My App.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers/reducers';
import { Header } from './components/common/Header';

let store   = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={ store }>
                <View style={ styles.container }>
                    <Header title="Tech Stack"/>
                </View>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

My reducers.js in the folder src/reducers:

```
console.log('HELLO');
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
console.log( combineReducers );
import LibraryReducer from './LibraryReducer';

const reducers = combineReducers({
    libraries: LibraryReducer
});

export default reducers;

// Fixed the log. When i'm loggin combineReducers i get undefined.
```

LibraryReducer.js

```
import data from '../data/LibraryList.json';

export default () => data;

Console errors: 
[Error log][1]
```

data json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "React",
        "description": "JS framework"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Vue",
        "description": "JS framework"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Angular",
        "description": "JS framework"
    }
]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "redux",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

THANK YOU ALL for your suggestions!

SOLVED:
Started a new project but don't gave it the name redux itself.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have the same issue as [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1681).

TLDR: rename the folder you have called `redux` to something else, wipe your `node_modules` and reinstall and it should work.

Comment: Still no success :/

Comment: After undoing the rename, try merging your code into a non-broken branch. I had this problem and that resolved it for me, though I do not understand how.

Answer (score 2):

We looked at a lot of different things, but the problem was one with module resolution. `import { combineReducers } from 'redux'` was not working, apparently because the project, itself, was given the name 'redux' in its package.json file and/or because a folder in the project's root was named 'redux'.

Comment: Are you getting the same error, or a different one?

Comment: The same one. the first time (after hot reloading) i get the error

object.defineProperty called of non-object

But when I refresh the emulator manually I get the same as before.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but i still get the same message.

Comment: Give this a shot - rename your `redux` folder to `store`. This may be a name collision issue.

Comment: Still no luck :/ 

folder structure: src/reducers

Comment: I'm running out of suggestions - can you `console.log(combineReducers)` in the reducers file? It seems to be a problem with importing `combineReducers`.

Comment: Right, it would also be nice to log `combineReducers` in the reducers.js file after you import it. It looks to me like you may have multiple problems in the project setup. The root of this issue seems to be that the `import { combineReducers } from 'redux'` is failing for for some as yet unknown reason.

Comment: Also, from the command line, please run `npm list redux`. This will tell you which version of redux, if any, is installed.

Comment: I'm trying to log my combineReducer but the log is not appearing. Even if I try to log 'Hello world' it isn't. I get version redux@4.0.1 when running that command.

Comment: Can you add `console.log(combineReducers)` just after you import `combineReducers` - on the very next line?

Comment: @PeeJee try to install the following  `npm i redux@4.0.0 --save` dont forget you need to add react-redux also `npm i react-redux --save`

Comment: Make sure you have gotten rid of any files or folders named redux. See [this comment](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1681#issuecomment-216508641) from Dan Abramov about how and why that can cause name collisions.

Comment: I fixed the console logs. When I'm logging the combinedReducer i get undefined.

Comment: So, this is definitely an issue with the import of `combineReducers` failing. Have you deleted 'node_modules' and run `npm install` again after making sure you've removed all files and folders named redux? The problem is not a redux or react problem. Rather, it seems to be a module-resolution problem.

Comment: Yes i deleted every folder that has the name redux. Deleted my node modules folder and did an npm install. But it didn't work so i tried to downgrade a version of redux by doing 'yarn remove redux' and yarn add redux@4.0.0'. But nothing seems working. I think i will try to build a fresh new project and try it again.

Comment: I think that's your best bet. Before you do, you might want to rename your project in the `package.json` from `redux` to something else. It's generally a good idea to not have your project or files or folders in your project share names with project dependencies.

Comment: I made a new project and everything works finally! I do not know what the problem was. Maybe that my app name was redux. But anyway thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I had the same problem because I renamed a folder to "redux". After undoing the rename, the problem persisted. I am using git and had to merge the code into a non-broken branch to fix this. I do not understand this solution, but it did help me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add this here as I came across this same issue today and luckily I quickly figured out the issue! The reason this error appeared in my builds was because I use the **babel module resolver plugin** and I named one of my module resolvers **redux**  If anyone comes across this answer, make sure you don't name any of your babel module resolvers the same as an NPM package.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all i would install ReduxThunk on your project folder, so run following:

```
npm i redux-thunk --save
```

next in your `App.js` import this lib like so

```
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
```

then create the Redux Store

```
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))
```

the Method for creating the reducers functions should be at the end of your `reducers.js` file like so.

```
const reducers  = combineReducers({
    libraries,
    //otherFunctions...
});

export default reducers;
```

don´t forget to import the combineReducers method from redux in your `reducers.js` file.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
```

combineReducers method accept functions that you previously declared in your `reducers.js` for expample following ( im writing...)

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { isLoggedIn: false }
function libraries(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
   switch (action.type) {       

     default:
      return state
   }
 }
```

you should be able to write many cases for the `switch` statement as you want. for example..

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { isLoggedIn: false }
function libraries(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
   switch (action.type) { 

     case "isLogginSuccess":
      return {...state, isLoggedIn: action.payload}

     default:
      return state
   }
 }
```

the reducer case "isLogginSuccess" should be trigered by calling another funcion inse your desired component.

Comment: @PeeJee which version of redux have you installed? share a picture of the package.json file please

Comment: @PeeJee everythig  looks good. could you please add the code from your index.js file and all other components like App.js and reducers.js ?

Comment: aight! Made my changes.

Comment: @PeeJee try to remove all console.logs from your reducers.js

Comment: @PeeJee and in your reducers.js change following 

`const reducers = combineReducers({
    libraries = ()
 => {}, });`

Comment: Didn't work. But when i log combineReducers I get undefined.

Comment: but why are you trying to log the combineReducers method. it make no sense.

Comment: To see if there is something wrong with the import.

Comment: ok i just created a snack on expo for you... here you can play around .. let me know if that helps you. upvote would be nice [click here for snack on Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@lui5778/redux)